# Is 'log(m)' a valid unit

Tags: probability-distributions, logarithms, unit-of-measure

I want to plot a particle size distribution.

A typical way to do this is plotting a probability density funtion `f(d)` over the diameter d. The unit of `d` is `[m]`, and the unit of `f` is `[1/m]`. The area under this curve equals 1.

However if the x-Axes of the graph has a logarithmic scale, the unit of the y-Axis needs to be adapted to ensure that the area under the curve remains 1.

How to correctly label these axis, e.g.:

- Option 1: x: `log(d), [m]`, y: `f(d), [1/log(m)]`
- Option 2:  x: `log(d), [log(m)]`, y: `f(log(d)), [1/log(m)]`
- Option 3:  x: `log(d / m), [1]`, y: `f(log(d / m)), [1]`
- Option 4:  x: `log(d), [log(m)]`, y: `f(d), [1/log(d)]`

Option 1 is often seen, but I have doubts if taking a logaritmus of a unit `log(m)` is allowed. Option 2 is a variant of option 1. In option 3, I'm avoiding the problem by making the argument of the logarithums dimensionless. However this is not very elegant in my opinion, since I am mixing variables and dimensions in `f(log(d / m))`. The last option is sometimes seen in publications, However I think `1/log(d)` is just wrong, since no information on the unit of d is given (ft or m).

Questions:

- What is the scientific correct labeling of these axis?
- Is it correct to state `log (m) = log ( 1000 mm) = 3 + log (mm)`?
- Things get even more weired, if have combination of units. E.g. How to convert `m/log(m)` to `mm/log(mm)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the arguments of transcendental functions are unitless. A logarithmic scale is not

$$\log x$$ but $$\log\frac xu$$ where $u$ is some reference magnitude, in the same unit as $x$.